# Tricky Chain Rule/Differentation/Derivative/Ellipse problem

Tags: calculus, geometry, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

[image]

When I found the derivative I got:

$$\frac{1}{2}x+ 2y\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{-1}{2}x}{2y}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-1x}{4y}$$

But I cannot plug in $(4, 0)$ and since point $Q$ is NOT in the circle equation.

By the way the "solution" is $$y = \frac{-x}{2\sqrt{3}} + \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$$

But I don't know how that is the solution? Since its from the answer key without steps shown

I mean I could guess and check the slope and plug in any value in the circle equation:
$$y = \pm \sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{4}x^{2}}$$

since the domain of $x$ is $(-2, 2)$.

But this is obviously not how you solve it.*emphasized text*

Comment: Well, you know immediately that the equation of the line is $y=a(4-x)$ for some $a$; you know that $a = \frac{x}{4y}$ for some $(x,y)$ on the ellipse.  Does that help any?

Comment: You could cheat: stretch the ellipse to a circle, solve the problem with trig, stretch it back again, then rationalize your answer with calculus.  ;)

Comment: @MegaboofMD No... it simplifies to 1/2 after applying the power rule of derivatives. The OP has that correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, let point of tangency $P(h, k)$ on the ellipse hence it will satisfy the equation of the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{4}+y=1$ as follows $$\frac{h^2}{4}+k^2=1\tag 1$$
Now, the slope of the tangent at the point $(h, k)$ is $$\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)_{(h, k)}=\text{slope of line PQ joining the points}\ (h, k) \ \text{&}\ (4, 0) $$ $$\frac{-h}{4k}=\frac{k-0}{h-4}$$ 
$$-h^2+4h=4k^2\iff \frac{h^2}{4}+k^2=h\tag 2$$
Now, comparing (1) & (2), we get 
$$h=1$$
Hence, setting this value of $h$ in (1), we get $$\frac{(1)^2}{4}+k^2=1$$ $$k^2=\frac{3}{4}\iff k=\pm\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$$ 
Since, the point $P$ is in the first quadrant its y-coordinate $k$ will be positive i.e. $k=\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$ so we have $P\left(1, \frac{\sqrt3}{2}\right)$

Hence, the equation of the tangent PQ joining the points $P\left(1, \frac{\sqrt3}{2}\right)$ & $Q(4, 0)$ is given as $$y-0=\frac{\frac{\sqrt3}{2}-0}{1-4}(x-4)$$
$$\color{red}{x+2y\sqrt 3-4=0}$$

Answer (score 0):

Differentiate using Chain Rule getting equation of tangent ( some steps omitted )

$$ \frac{x x_P}{4} + \frac{y y_P}{1} =1  \tag{1} $$

You are given

$$ x=x_Q=4,y=y_Q=0, \rightarrow x_P= 1 \tag{2}$$

Substitute into equation  of ellipse, you get $ y_P= \frac{\sqrt3}{2} \tag{3}$

Tangent line has equation:

$$\frac{x\cdot 1}{4} + \frac {y \sqrt 3}{2} =1. \tag{4}$$